# Is there a way to count occurrences of a string in an HTML document using XPATH in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I've tried the following:

```
=IMPORTXML(B6, "count(//text()[contains(., 'string')])")
```

where cell `B6` = the URL of the HTML document

and `'string'` = the desired text string to count within the HTML doc

The goal is to get an accurate count of string occurrences that appear in the `<body>` of the document.

I'm assuming that the `IMPORTXML` function is the only way this might be possible. If not, is there another solution?

Comment: and ... ? did you get the information ? because your formula is correct ! i.e. `=IMPORTXML("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784066/is-there-a-way-to-count-occurrences-of-a-string-in-an-html-document-using-xpath", "count(//text()[contains(., 'xpath')])")`

Comment: So when B6 =  https://takethereinsstl.org/ and the string = "louis", I get a returned value of "1" from the G Sheet function. However, performing a search in the Chrome browser for "louis" on the webpage, I get 8 results.

Comment: With this url, you will not be able to find all the data because the page is partially built on your side (by javascript / json) and not totally on the server side. So Google will not be able to give informations. For example `= IMPORTXML (B6," count (// text () [contains (., 'Equine')]) ")` only gives 3 instead of 9 when the page is fully loaded and built on the client side.

Comment: here is a full explanation https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun ... `all starts with disabling JavaScript for the website to see what's left and what's possible to be scrapped`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(UNIQUE(LOWER(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*")), 
 "where Col1 contains 'louis'"))), "louis", "♥"), "[^♥]", ))))
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.